# How would I get or generate the image of a web page from its url in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, ruby-on-rails-3, url

I want to retrieve or generate an image of a web page starting with the page's url. How would I do this in ruby?

More specifically, I'd like the image to be of the full webpage and to have complete control over its size.

Comment: Its a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947642/create-a-website-screenshot-thumbnail-server-side

Comment: you need some type of render engine (web kit??) then I suppose from there you can take the rendered page and save it as an image.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `thumbnailer service`

Here is the code snippet: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3621

Comment: it would be nice to have some documentation or at least an explanation along with the code...

Comment: URL is broken now